# Load SVG in VueJS component and set classes

Tags: css, svg, vuejs2

How should I load an SVG image in a component so that the css styles in the component will be applied to the SVG image elements according to classes ?

For instance, I have the class `foo` in this element of the SVG image:

```
<circle class="foo" cx="70" cy="405" r="10" />
```

And this class in my vue component:

```
.foo {
  fill: red;
}
```

Comment: just like that it should be applied, is it not applying it?

Comment: @Michael I'd like the svg file to be loaded as an external svg file but still using the css set in the component.

Comment: what do you mean by external? where is it rendered?